# How can I call a serverless lambda function with a role from another function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I want to call a lambda function with a custom role from another function using serverless framework, what should I do, I have given the invoke permissions but it seems it is not enough, since the other function as some more permission which is given by the role

The error I am getting,

```
ocr-solution-dev-routes is not authorized to perform:textract:StartDocumentAnalysis",
"errorType":"AccessDeniedException"
```

My serverless yml

```
iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
       - "s3:*"
      Resource: { "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.secrets.IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME}", "/*" ] ] }
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - lambda:InvokeFunction
        - lambda:InvokeAsync
      Resource: "*"

    functions:
      routes:
        handler: src/functions/routes/handler.run
        events:
          - s3:
              bucket: ${self:custom.secrets.IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME}
              event: s3:ObjectCreated:*

      startTextract:
        role: QvaliaTextractRole
        handler: src/functions/routes/handler.startTextAnalysis

      getTextract:
        role: QvaliaTextractRole
        handler: src/functions/routes/handler.detectTextAnalysis

    resources:
      Resources:
        QvaliaTextractRole:
          Type: AWS::IAM::Role
          Properties:
            RoleName: QvaliaTextractRole
            AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
              Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Principal:
                  Service:
                    - textract.amazonaws.com
                    - lambda.amazonaws.com
                Action:
                - sts:AssumeRole
            Policies:
              - PolicyName: TextractPolicy
                PolicyDocument:
                  Version: '2012-10-17'
                  Statement:
                    - Effect: Allow
                      Action:
                        - lambda:*
                        - sns:*
                        - sqs:*
                        - s3:*
                      Resource: "*"

                    - Effect: "Allow"
                      Action:
                        - "s3:*"
                      Resource: { "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.secrets.IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME}", "/*" ] ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to your role the `AmazonTextractFullAccess` policy, as described in the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/api-async-roles.html)

```
iamManagedPolicies:
 - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonTextractFullAccess
```